# Get count of span value in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I retrieve data from the database as in controller:

```
$users = DB::select("select users.id, users.name, users.email, count(is_read) as unread 
        from users LEFT  JOIN  messagesnews ON users.id = messagesnews.from and is_read = 0 and messagesnews.to = " . Auth::id() . "
       where users.id != " . Auth::id() . " 
        group by users.id, users.name, users.email");
return view('admin.home.index', compact('users'));
```

in view:

```
@foreach($users as $user)                                  
    @if($user->unread)
      <span class="pending">{{ $user->unread }}</span>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

work nice
[image]

How can I get just one number to calculate of them **6**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
 @php $totlUnread = 0; @endphp
 @foreach($users as $user)                                  
    @if($user->unread)
        @php $totlUnread+=$user->unread; @endphp
     @endif
@endforeach
@php echo "<span class='pending'>$totlUnread</span>"; @endphp
```

Comment: thank you but give me this error 
syntax error, unexpected 'pending' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: made changes. now please try

Comment: give me 0 number

Comment: change to `@php echo "<span class='pending'>$totlUnread</span>"; @endphp`

Comment: sorry, made one more change. I am answering you form my mobile phone.

Comment: feel free to ask questions.

Comment: You are super star thank you very much I have 4 hours try to solve it myself

Answer (score 0):

```
        var sum = 0;
            $(".pending").each(function() {
                sum += parseInt($(this).html());
            });
            return sum;
```

or

```
   <?php 
    $all_unread = array_column($users, 'unread');
    array_sum($all_unread);
  ?>
```

Comment: Thank you I'll try it also :)